# keep the color in disabled check button html

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to show some check buttons but disabled to people. Just showing some info from my database.

I already did the part of showing the disabled buttons but they appear in grey and is difficult to see if they are checked or not. Is there a way to keep the color but make them static?

This is one of my buttons:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked id="checkBox159_1" name="option1" value="1">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick='return false;'  checked id="checkBox159_1" name="option1" value="1">
```

place a `return false;` in your onClick event will avoid default behavior

Is that what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/Xd2ZP/

Comment: You are the man!. Thank you. The button is clickable but it does nothing. amazing.